# laravel 5: latest()->get() not giving accurate result

Tags: laravel

I am newbie on Laravel, I am working on a project on Laravel 5.

I am trying to get result in descending order based on created_at. But I am getting result in ascending orders only.

This is my controller file

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Position;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PositionController extends Controller {
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $positions = Position::latest()->get();
    print_r($positions);

}
```

This is my model file

```
<?php namespace App;

   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

   class Position extends Model {

    //

   }
```

Please advice me what wrong am I doing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried likes this?:

```
public function index()
{
    $positions = Position::orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')->get();
    print_r($positions);

}
```

Comment: $positions = Position::orderBy('created_at', 'DSC')->get(); this gives me desired result, but I want to know why latest()->get() is not working

Answer (score 1):

```
public function index()
{
    $positions = Position::oldest()->get();
    print_r($positions);

}
```

Using both methods you get the same query string, so it's really odd that you are getting different outputs.

```
>>> App\Category::oldest()->toSql()
=> "select * from `categories` where `categories`.`deleted_at` is null order by `created_at` asc"

>>> App\Category::orderBy('created_at','ASC')->toSql()
=> "select * from `categories` where `categories`.`deleted_at` is null order by `created_at` asc"

>>> App\Category::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->toSql()
=> "select * from `categories` where `categories`.`deleted_at` is null order by `created_at` desc"

>>> App\Category::latest()->toSql()
=> "select * from `categories` where `categories`.`deleted_at` is null order by `created_at` desc"
```

Comment: this is displaying same results

Comment: Can you verify if your positions table has created_at and updated_at properly populated fields?

Comment: I have created them using seeds, but manually changed created_at datetime, also having same issue with another table as well where I havent used seed to enter data into table

Comment: $positions = Position::orderBy('created_at', 'DSC')->get(); this gives me perfect result

Comment: "App\Position::latest()->get();" giving me proper result on 'php artisan tinker'